# using array_push to add key/value element to array

Tags: php, arrays

I am looping through an array, upon finding a duplicate key, I am trying to add it as another element of key/value.

The data looks something like this

```
[139432,97]
[139432,11400]
[139440,97]
[139440,7898]
```

So as you can see, the first element is to be the key, and any matches on that key should be a key/value so the result:

```
139432 => '97', '11400'
139440 => '97', '7898'
```

So I using the following, to either create a new array, or push new values to existing array:

```
if(isset($output[$key])) {
    array_push($output[$key], array( 'volume' => $temp[1] ));         
}       
else { 
    $output[$key] = array( 'score' => $temp[1]);         
}
```

So what I am getting looks like this:

```
 array (size=31)
  139432 => 
    array (size=2)
      'score' => int 97
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'volume' => int 11400
  139440 => 
    array (size=2)
      'score' => int 97
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'volume' => int 7898
```

I don't want the 'volume' part to be another array, what I simply want is:

```
array (size=31)
  139432 => 
    array (size=2)
      'score' => int 97          
      'volume' => int 11400
  139440 => 
    array (size=2)
      'score' => int 97
      'volume' => int 7898
```

How is my use of creating, adding to the array incorrect ?

Comment: Then why do you use `array_push()` ?!

Comment: How do you know which one is `score` and which one is `volume`?

Comment: looks like score always comes first. if the key is set, you know you're on the second one

Comment: @tuananh at this stage I am making assumption as the data comes in, the first one is 'score' and the subsequent value will be 'volume'

Comment: @Rizier123 well this is why i'm asking the question - how else to do it ?

Comment: You asked how you get the volume not i a separate array, so just remove array_push() ?! ...

Comment: @Rizier123 I tried it without array_push, there is no difference, I cannot get the array to be like my desired outcome above

Comment: @yoyoma Then make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put them into the array like this.  I think it would create the output you desire.

```
    if(array_key_exists($key, $output)) {
        $output[$key]['volume']=$temp[1];
        //array_push($output[$key], array( 'volume' => $temp[1] ));         
    }       
    else {
        $output[$key]['score']=$temp[1];
        //$output[$key] = array( 'score' => $temp[1]);         
    }
```

Comment: We were already there 15 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736415/using-array-push-to-add-key-value-element-to-array#comment49528962_30736415

Comment: asking why they are using array_push is different than showing an alternative to array_push.....but yeah it looks like several people identified the issue and OP could have figured it out from there

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `array_push` for that. This should work:

```
if(isset($output[$key])) {
    if(isset($output[$key]['score'])) {
        $output[$key]['volume'] = $temp[1];         
    }       
    else { 
        $output[$key] = array( 'score' => $temp[1]);         
    }
}
```